# Socket.io P2P connection in nodejs (more than one ports on same server)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to ask that on a Socket.io P2P connection in node.js when two clients connected on the same server, It is possible that they are connected by different ports on the same server.and can share means chat with each other.

Comment: Wierd question, If a node server is running, it can only open one port, so the answer is simply no if you have asked the question correctly. I would read up on how socket.io works, https://socket.io/

Comment: thanks for your answer.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating multiple instances of the node.js server and initialize multiple instance os socket.io on each of the ports

```
var app = require('express')();
var http1 = require('http').Server(app).listen(8080);
var http2 = require('http').Server(app).listen(9090);
var io1 = require('socket.io')(http);
var io2 = require('socket.io')(http);
```

But then also as there will be a single process all the requests will be ultimately transferred from the main port only. The original server.  Due top this there is no benefit of using more then one socket.

Refer [this](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) for more info

Comment: I am also trying this for the first time and haven't tried it for chatting. I don't actually think it will work due to the link I posted. But you can always give it a shot. Work or not you will learn something new